# Cannot delete Instagram realtime subscriptions

Tags: real-time, instagram, real-time-updates

I am running into an issue where I can subscribe to realtime updates on tags but I cannot delete these subscriptions.

Subscribing works fine, and I can prove that the subscription step works by GET'ing the subscription list:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=SECRET&client_id=ID'


{"meta":{"code":200},
"data":[{"object":"tag",
    "object_id":"winter",
    "aspect":"media",
    "callback_url":"http:\/\/SITE.com:7000\/ig",
    "type":"subscription",
    "id":"4747294"},
    {"object":"tag",
    "object_id":"snow",
    "aspect":"media",
    "callback_url":"http:\/\/SITE.com:7000\/ig",
    "type":"subscription",
    "id":"4747295"}]}
```

This yields two tag subscriptions (winter and snow, in my case). However, the same code taken from the Instagram Developer instructions for deleting subscriptions is failing:

```
curl -X DELETE 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=SECRET&object=all&client_id=ID'


Oops, an error occurred.
```

Is this an Instagram-side problem or is my DELETE command erroneous?

Comment: I am getting the same error as well. are you receiving updates at all?

Comment: I also tested it with apigee console, and I am getting the same error.

Comment: It seems to have resolved today. My script auto-retries and at some point today it started working. Their API mysteriously failing without any useful error message is sort of like a compiler with bugs (but much more common).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the same error with code that had been working, so the problem appears to be on their side.  I would suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: Because they shut down their mailing list and referred us all to StackOverflow, I thought this *was* the place where bugs were reported. But indeed there is a place to report bugs: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=364531043625021